# how to paste image on google slides with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, copy-paste, google-slides

i'm trying to paste a .jpg image from my clipboard to a slide in a google slides presentation, but nothing happens. I'm currently using selenium ActionChains to execute the action. I even tried pasting a text insted of an image... still nothing

code:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.DOWN).key_up(Keys.DOWN).perform() 
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.DOWN).key_up(Keys.DOWN).perform() #going down to the slide
time.sleep(1)
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
time.sleep(10)
```

I'd like to avoid using google slide API, because if I'm not wrong it need the image URL, which i do not have, and making it woulndn't work with what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to download the image and add it to your Google Drive, you can try the following code. (the idea is to navigate to the Insert Menu and choose to import the image from Google Drive):

```
action.key_down(Keys.ALT).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down('i').key_up(Keys.ALT).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up('i').perform()
action.key_down(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).key_up(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
action.key_down(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).key_up(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).perform()
for i in range(2):
    action.key_down(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).key_up(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
action.key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
action.key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform() 
action.key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```